# How can a django developer tell which code is the better one to use

Tags: django

I must say, I am really loving django and how the framework handles a lot of things, but sometimes, it just seems like there are way too many ways to do the same thing, that sometimes one just wants to know if a particular way is best. I have a filtering line of code that I initially wrote like this..

```
Post.objects.filter(author=user).filter(approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')
```

I was going through my codes and just thought to change this line to

```
Post.objects.filter(author=user, approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')
```

I knew it would still work, but was still surprised it did the exact same thing. So, my question is, in a situation like this, how would one know which is the better implementation here? Cos both lines of code do filtering on the database level.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, these different expressions will (I think) result in the same SQL being executed. Until your python code needs to know the answers out of this, the query won't be executed.  You can call the .explain() method on each to see more about what the database operations are.

[Django docs, querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

That being said, I think they are the same in this example only because filter() with two fields always implies a logical 'and' between them, so the results will be the same.  With some of the other functions perhaps there could be some logic in the precedence that will change the resulting queryset and SQL.